# Change specials and discounts to percents in Opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I'm newbee in Opencart development, so help me please. Opencart version 2.1.
http://prntscr.com/dak2kf
http://prntscr.com/dak3xi
I want to change current discounts and specials to percent type.
What files i need to change for right showing in cart and order?
I changed controller of product, on products page price already right (42% discount), but to cart sending price without 42% discount, just 42 value.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our suggestion is to use jquery and convert the % to fixed price before saving it to the database.

This way Opencart functionality will not be affected and you will be able to    set price for special deal with ease.

You can convert % to fixed price on blur from the input field.
});